# I am confused as to how my dependencies change every render?

Tags: reactjs

```
   // We are only running this at initial render and anytime
  // yelpResults gets updated (only once per food and location submit)
  useEffect(() => {
    // Creating a temp array so our restaurantIndexes is immutable
    let tempArray = [];

    // Concatenating the value of each index into our state
    Object.keys(yelpResults).map((index) =>  tempArray.push(index));
    
    // Saving the results of our restaurant indexes
    setRestaurantIndexes(tempArray);
  }, [yelpResults, restaurantIndexes]);
```

Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.

Comment: Your dependency array should be `[yelpResults]`. Having `restaurantIndexes` as a dependency will cause the effect to run every time restaurantIndexes udates, which happens inside the effect (causing an infinite loop).

Comment: Btw, your effect simplifies to `setRestaurantIndexes(Object.keys(yelpResults))`

Comment: Thanks that makes sense! Isn’t it best practice to make a temporary array so it’s immutable? I’m not sure if I’m understanding correctly but it’s something I saw on a video when learning it

Comment: Arrays in JS are mutable, using the push method mutates the array. Also you used the `let` keyword, use `const` instead so it's init only. What you should be really concerned about here is mutating the `yelpResults`, which you don't.

Comment: Also (unless this example has been simplified), restaurantIndexes is derived state. That means you can always figure out what it should be based on some other data (in this case, yelpResults). You should probably replace this effect and state with `const restaurantIndexes = Object.keys(yelpResults);`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are doing wrong is you are re-rendering things when one of these values changes `[yelpResults, restaurantIndexes]` because `useEffect` renders again when value changes.So a better solution would be to put an `if` statement which will check if the value has changed or not.

```
 const [restaurantIndexes, setRestaurantIndexes] = useState("")

 useEffect(() => {
       // Creating a temp array so our restaurantIndexes is immutable
       let tempArray = [];

       // Concatenating the value of each index into our state
       Object.keys(yelpResults).map((index) =>  tempArray.push(index));
       
       console.log(tempArray);

       //Check if tempArray has changed
       if(restaurantIndexes !== tempArray) return
       // Set the RestaurantIndex state
       setRestaurantIndexes(tempArray);
       
  }, [yelpResults,restaurantIndexes]);
```

Comment: Checking whether dependencies have changed is the exact responsibility of the useEffect api (and react updates on general). Unless you need to use a different comparison implementation, this is always a mistake. Also, arrays are objects (reference types) in JavaScript so the equality comparison won't work.